# Does vsnprintf() use all va_list arguments even if the output is truncated?

Tags: c++, c, variadic-functions

I am making a log function that has a printf-like function: `log(LOG_LEVEL lvl, const char* fmt, ...)`.

`LOG_LEVEL` is just an enum (0 is critical, higher are less important).

If `lvl` is higher than another variable (say, `current_log_level`), I want to do as little as possible and return fast. However, I'm afraid of breaking the stack by not using the parameters after `fmt`, and I would like to avoid writing my own "check fmt and call va_arg() as required" if possible to avoid possible discrepancies with the `printf` format, so I thought about using `vsnprintf` and just have the length of the output string as small as possible.

According to the docs, for `vsnprintf`, if the length is set to 0, the output string can be null but I am not sure if that would use all the remaining arguments or if it just stops processing there and returns.

Imagine the following (I'm using C++17 but I think this also applies to good old C):

```
enum class LOG_LEVEL : unsigned int { ERROR, WARNING };

LOG_LEVEL current_log_level = LOG_LEVEL::WARNING;

void log(LOG_LEVEL lvl, const char* fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);

    if (static_cast<unsigned int>(lvl) <= static_cast<unsigned int>(current_log_level))
    {
        /* lock a mutex, write to a file and/or whatever */
    }
    else
    {
        vsnprintf(nullptr, 0, fmt, args);
    }

    va_end(args);
}
```

I feel that `vsnprintf` (and other v*printf functions) should use all the args even if it truncates, (if not, that'd be a nice security issue in many programs), but it is not mentioned in the man pages and I could not find any information. Maybe my search-fu was not good enough. Or maybe there is a better, faster and/or easier way to do this?

Comment: Why are you concerned that all arguments are "used" exactly? The caller knows how many arguments it pushed and will clean up when your function returns.

Comment: "breaking the stack by not using the parameters" is not something that can happen.

Comment: Ok, I think I was confused and now looking at the comments I might have found my problem. I saw in the man pages that you should not use too many times va_arg() but not that I should not use it too few times."If  there  is  no next argument, or if type is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument (as promoted according to the default argument promotions), random errors will occur."

Comment: So I guess my reply is: No need to worry if you use *less* arguments than passed? Just need to worry if you try to use more arguments than passed. I was thinking that as the stack frame is not known by the compiler (unknown number of parameters), if not all were used then when you return the stack would get corrupted. No?

Comment: Arguments are pushed (by necessity) _before_ the return address. When you enter the function, the return address is therefore always at the top of stack. When your function is done it can simply return (ie reset the stack pointer to its position when the function started and jump back to the calling function. The calling function knows how many arguments it pushed and can just adjust the stack pointer accordingly.

Comment: In short, if you want the function to do as little as possible when the log level condition is not satisfied, you can move everything into the branch where the log level condition is satisfied, including the `va_start()`, `va_end()`, and `v*printf()` calls. Although the `log()` function will do as little as possible, the arguments of the `log()` call will still be evaluated by the caller. You should rename the function though because `log` is a reserved function name in C.

Comment: Why did you add C and C++? What you think doesn't matter. They are different languages.

Comment: "What you think doesn't matter. They are different languages". I agree, but my question was applicable to both languages so I added both tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does vsnprintf() use all va_list arguments even if the output is truncated?

Is an implementation detail. The result *has to be* truncated. *How* is it implemented is not specified - potentially, `vsnprintf` source code can check if the output is longer and then stop processing.

> I feel that vsnprintf (and other v*printf functions) should use all the args even if it truncate

I feel that is an unjustified feeling. Arguments exists on stack, they are there. If they are not accessed, they are not accessed, nothing happens.

Do nothing when you want to do nothing. Early return looks like a style to use here.

```
void log(LOG_LEVEL lvl, const char* fmt, ...)  {
    if (static_cast<unsigned int>(lvl) > static_cast<unsigned int>(current_log_level)) {
          return;
    }
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    /* lock a mutex, write to a file and/or whatever */
    va_end(args);
}
```

Consider adding `__attribute__((__printf__(2,3)))` for gcc compiler to issue formatting warinings.

But then, in C++ use C++ streams or `std::format`.

> I was thinking that as the stack frame is not known by the compiler (unknown number of parameters), if not all were used then when you return the stack would get corrupted. No?

Bottom line, no. It is implemented in such a way that that does not happen. If you are interested in implementation details *for x86 standard System V ABI* you can read https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/x86_64-abi-0.99.pdf relevant sections about `va_list` and friends .

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I wanted to know